Weird ^[[0K characters in git diff output (git delta)
I've been trying to make my git diff output nicer. Mainly I want side-by-side output, and so, I went with git-delta. Everything has been working great, but there is only one problem: git diff output contains weird character '^[[0K' at ends of lines (I guess it's an EOL character).
I would like to get rid of it, basically. Is this a configuration problem?
Git Diff Output with the unwanted EOL characters
I installed ydiff, but couldn't get it working either through 'git diff' command; 'git difftool' worked as expected. For git-delta, I've scrambled around the configuration and can't really come up with any more attempts.

It looks like an escape sequence to color the output

Is there a way to hide these sequences?

^[ is one of the ways to display the ESC character.
Apparently ESC [ <n> K is supposed to be

Replace all text on the line with the cursor specified by <n> with space characters.

where the 0 for <n> means

0 erases from the current cursor position (inclusive) to the end of the line/display


Is there a way to hide these special characters?

would this question help? It would depend on how you view the result (OS, terminal)
